# Can't spot a the problem in my code for array assortment in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So i have an assignment, i need to turn all 1's in an array into the distance from the closest 0.
And so when i run it, the last number in the output stays as 1, when it should have changed into a 2.
can someone help me spot my mistake?

Basically what zeroDistance does, is pass the array once, changing all values, then runs from the back and changes them all again.

```
    public static void zeroDistance (int [] a)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == 0)
            counter = 0;
        if (a[i] == 1)
        {
            counter++;
            a[i] = counter;
        }
    }
    counter = 0;
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (a[i] == 0)
            counter = 0;
        if (a[i] != 0)
        {
            counter++;
            if (a[i] > counter)
                a[i] = counter;
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
int[] a={0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1};
```

Output:

```
zeroDistance method result : 
0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1
Should return : 
0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? An ability to use a debugger is very valuable.

Comment: It may be easier if you just set non-zero elements to `precedingElement + 1`: there is no need for the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the second loop. Since you start over **from the end** of the array, your second loop considers that **you have** encountered a 0 at the end of your array, which is obviously **not** the case here.

So according to your code in your second loop `if (a[i] > counter)` will be true, since `a[1]` **is 2** and `counter` **is 1** in your first iteration, that leading to your last member of your array being 1 in your result.

As other people said. Don't change values before you encounter a zero. Don't assume that the end of your array is a 0. If you want to fix your problem you can set `counter = a[a.length - 1];` before your second loop. But that is not very sexy, I think you can come up with another approach for your problem.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

As Robby pointed out. You will also get a problem in your first loop if you have a 1 at the beginning.

That being said, here is a version that seems to work on my side. Don't hesitate to point out any error.

```java
public static void zeroDistance (int[] a)
{
    List<Integer> zerosCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        if (a[i] == 0)
            zerosCoordinates.add(i);
    }

    for(int i : zerosCoordinates) {

        for (int j = i - 1, k = 1; j >= 0; j--, k++) {

            if (a[j] == 0)
                break;

            if (a[j] != 0 && a[j] < k)
                a[j] = k;
        }
    }

    for (int i : zerosCoordinates) {

        for (int j = i + 1, k = 1; j < a.length; j++, k++) {

            if (a[j] == 0)
                break;

            if (a[j] != 0 && a[j] > k || j == a.length - 1)
                a[j] = k;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        System.out.print(a[i]);
}
```

There is surely a better way to do this. I did it in a rush sorry about that.

Comment: The problem is not only in the second loop. If the array starts with 1, results will be incorrect because of how the first loop operates.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change any values before you encounter the first zero.

You can do this by using an additional flag in which you keep track of whether a zero has been encountered in the current pass.